# Show subitems in C# ListView when using Tile view

Tags: c#, listview

I'm using ListView component to display some saved profiles in my program, each profile has an icon and a title. So I used, the ListView with *View* property set to *Tile* (also groupping was applied)

How I wan't to add some description text about the entries (not a tooltip). Can I do it like Windows Explorer does?

[image: Windows Explorer Tile view, item details]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need to define column headers. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.view.aspx):

> The tile view displays each item with
>   a large icon on the left and textual
>   information on the right. The textual
>   information consists of the item label
>   followed by subitems. By default, only
>   the first subitem is displayed, which
>   corresponds to the item label. To
>   display additional subitems, you must
>   add `ColumnHeader` objects to the
>   `Columns` collection. Each subitem in
>   the tile corresponds to a column
>   header. To control which subitems are
>   displayed and the order in which they
>   are displayed, you must set the
>   `ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem.Name`
>   property for each item and the
>   `ColumnHeader.Name` property for each
>   header. You can then add, remove, and
>   rearrange headers in the `Columns`
>   collection to achieve the desired
>   result.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will do exactly what you want, since I've only tested it without any kind of icon, but it will write the subitems when the ListView is in Tile mode.

First set `OwnerDraw` on your ListView to `true` and then add this function to its DrawItem event:

```
private void statisticsView_DrawItem(object sender,
    DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.Bounds);
    if((e.State & ListViewItemStates.Selected) != 0)
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();

    Rectangle bounds = e.Bounds;
    Font font = ((ListView)sender).Font;
    Font nameFont = new Font(font.FontFamily,
        font.Size,
        FontStyle.Underline | FontStyle.Bold,
        font.Unit,
        font.GdiCharSet,
        font.GdiVerticalFont);

    using(StringFormat sf = new StringFormat())
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.SubItems[0].Text,
            nameFont, Brushes.Black, bounds, sf);
        bounds.Y += 17;
        for(int i = 1; i < e.Item.SubItems.Count; ++i, bounds.Y += 15)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.SubItems[i].Text,
                font, Brushes.Black, bounds, sf);
    }
}
```

First it fills the tile with a white background colour and if the tile is selected it draws a selection rectangle around it. The next part just takes the font set on the ListView and creates a duplicate font with a few changes. Lastly it draws each of the subitems while moving the drawing rectangle down 15 pixels after each subitem. The first subitem is drawn with the separate font and is 17 pixels above the rest.

You should be able to modify the code to suit your needs.